# How to use Winmerge for archive compare

Tags: zip, 7-zip, winmerge, difftool

I need to compare `jar` files (i.e. `zip` files) with `java` files in it.
My WinMerge v. 2.14.0.0 Unicode refuses to work with my 7-zip v. 16.04 [64 bit]. The [official guide](http://manual.winmerge.org/Install.html#Installing_archive_support) did not help. Is there any exact instructions to compare archives with WinMerge?

Answer (score 2):

1. Download from the latest `DllBuild` in [sourceforge repository](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winmerge/files/7-zip-plugin/) 7z package (`Merge7z0028-465-920.7z` in my case).
2. Place `7z.dll` and `Merge7zXXXX.dll` (`Merge7z920U.dll` in my case) from the downloaded archive to the `WinMerge` install directory (`C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge\` in my system).

Answer (score 0):

Just install the latest version. Archive support via 7zip has been built in since at least WinMerge 2.15.2 - 2018-01-28.